# How can i write google chrome extension which will allow me to use it from javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, go

I have two implementation of Python and Go as stand-alone application which runs in user desktop, now the user goes to www.VPN-myprivate-VPN.com website and logs in.

After login via Chrome the user need to communicate with the python/go application using javascript from the browser code.

Is there any sample available to work with, so that javascript > to google chrome my extension > to local system access

Any suggestion please?

[image]

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: See my above EDIT scenario where the javascript will access the chrome extension and extension will allow the back-end GREEN / RED. Is that the link will do? or its just to make chrome apps u mean?

Comment: See Native Messaging section if you need to communicate with your native application. See Send messages from web pages section if you need to communicate with a websie.